# Is it possible to bring back not staged changes after git reset --hard HEAD@{1}?

Tags: git, git-reset

After a pull request, git showed a long list of staged files which I have not modified.
[image]

Then I've made the stupid decision to execute `git reset --hard HEAD@{1}` and lost the not staged changes.
Is there a solution to bring them back?

Comment: Perhaps using a recovery tool is your last option...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is not way to recover unstaged modified files.

Although you might want to look to your text editor history/undo files. More than once I recovered deleted files from there.

To revert a conflicting merge is safer to do a `git merge --abort`.

Comment: I've looked in both atom and notepad++, but without success.